# How to set pixel value into specific one if condition is met?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I have an image based on RGBA mode, it has a transparent background like below.

The red dot I have noted has a pixel value of `(2, 2, 3, 45)`, representing R, G, B, and alpha values.

I want to make all pixels, whose alpha value is lower than `45` turn to be `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. I searched for a while, but I only discovered that `numpy.where` has similar function, but it only suits to single data like R value or B value rather than whole pixel tuples:

Here is some pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```
if pixel's alpha value <= 45:
    pixel = (0,0,0,0)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you load your image? Is it a numpy array?

Comment: Yes,it is numpy array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) for that:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.uint8(np.ones((256, 256, 4)) * (255, 0, 0, 0))
alpha = np.uint8(np.expand_dims(np.arange(256), axis=1) * np.ones(256))
image[:, :, 3] = alpha

image_alpha_cut = image.copy()
image_alpha_cut[image_alpha_cut[:, :, 3] <= 45] = 0

cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('image_alpha_cut.png', image_alpha_cut)
```

Input image with gradient alpha channel:

[image: Input image]

Result image with cut alpha channel:

[image: Result image]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** To multiply the affected alpha values by a constant factor like `0.3`, you can do this:

```py
idx = image_alpha_cut[:, :, 3] < 40
image_alpha_cut[idx, 3] = 0.3 * image_alpha_cut[idx, 3]
```

Simple `image_alpha_cut[idx, 3] *= 0.3` doesn't work here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...].py", line 9, in <module>
    image_alpha_cut[idx, 3] *= 0.3
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

[image: Result image #2]

Comment: I didn't know it performs broadcasting for value assignments like this, thought right side needed to be [0, 0, 0, 0] or np.zeros(appropriate shape here).

Comment: @HansHirsse ,Hi , one more thing , what if i want `alpha value *= 0.3` rather than equal to 0? i want all alpha `value < 40` become `alpha value*=0.3`

Comment: @Super-ilad Please see my edit.